# Serializing data structure to an existing array using serde

Tags: rust, serde

I am trying to serialize a bunch of `enum Action {}` to a file which is expected to contain a RON array of `Action`s :

```
Action(..)
Action(..)
```

But for convenient deserialization I would prefer it in this format `Vec<Action>`:

```
[
  Action(..),
  Action(..),
]
```

The problem I am facing is I can use `ron::ser::to_string` to serialize a single `Action` item but how do I add it to a file already containing an array or if it's a blank file, create an array and then insert an `Action` ?

As the comments have pointed out, I could overwrite the entire file on each `Action` append but ideally I am allowing for the possibility of this file being too large for memory.

Comment: Generally you would deserialize the contents of the file, insert the action(s), then serialize it back.

Comment: Serialization is usually done in full. So deserialize the file, get the array, insert into it, serialize into a new array. If it's too costly - then ask yourself why do you need to serialize that often?

Comment: Maybe you can save the file every N updates

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov Thanks for your input. This file is actually a log file that's writing `Action` commands to a file with user activity. Hence, when I am writing to a file  I can just write `Action \n Action \n` so on, but to actually use this file I need to be able to conveniently deserialize the file into a `Vec<Action>`. Hence, the need for this question, that would it be possible to create this `Vector` during the serialization phase itself.

Comment: That sounds easier. You could replace serialization with plain writing to file using [appending](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.append) flag. And implement some custom deserializer that reads the file line by line to get the array

Comment: If you're always appending you could also do something similar to [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) where each line is an object (important: without linebreaks) and you can just append a line each time. Should be possible since [`to_string`](https://docs.rs/ron/latest/ron/ser/fn.to_string.html) *"does not generate any newlines"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to challenge one assumption of yours: Is deserialization of a list `[…,…,…]` into a `Vec<Action>` really that much more convenient? Here's how you deserialize a plain agglutination of `Action(…) Action(…)` into a `Vec<Action>`:

```rust
std::iter::from_fn({
    let mut de = ron::Deserializer::from_str(INPUT)?;
    move || {
        de.end()
            .is_err()
            .then_some(Action::deserialize::<_>(&mut de))
    }
})
.collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()
```

[Rust explorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#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)

If that's a little bit too much magic for your taste, you can go iteratively:

```rust
let mut res = Vec::new();
let mut de = ron::Deserializer::from_str(INPUT)?;
loop {
    let act = Action::deserialize::<_>(&mut de)?;
    res.push(act);
    if de.end().is_ok() {
        break;
    }
}
```

Serialization/saving is then a plain appending write (adding a newline is optional).

This goes into the JSONL direction @cafce25 suggested, but without the limitation that your RON must be newline-free. That being said, if you do go for RONL, it has the added benefit that if eventually one of your writes fails and you get a broken record, you can still parse all others. Which to go for depends on how often your file is viewed by humans vs how often it is appended.

Comment: Also I think this approach wouldn't work if I use `PrettyConfig` which serializes the structure over multiple lines

Comment: It would. Try randomly changing the newlines in the *Rust explorer* I linked.

Answer (score 1):

You can `seek` to remove the trailing `]` then insert the data there:

```rs
use std::fs::OpenOptions;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let action = Action {};

    let mut f = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .open("file.ron")
        .unwrap();;

    // move the cursor to 1 char before the end of the file, before the ]
    f.seek(SeekFrom::End(-1))?;
    // overwrite the ] with the new action then add another ] at the end.
    // Make sure to include the comma in between
    write!(f, ",\n{}]", ron::to_string(&action).unwrap()); // todo: proper error handling;
    Ok(())
}
```

This should result in a valid RON object being saved.

Note this is easy to break, for example accidentally adding a trailing line break at the end of the file will make this generate an invalid RON file.

Comment: Hm, to make this more robust, maybe read the last 500-or-so bytes, find the last `]`, and replace from there? (And error out if `]` isn't found and the file isn't empty.)

Comment: @Caesar You'd probably want to assert that the last non-whitespace character is in fact `]` because if it's `}` or something else the file is not in the format you expect you may not want to write there at all

Comment: You're right, the last `]` won't do. (But even then, if somebody adds a comment like // [Foo] at the end, things may get weird.)